# Does file file_get_contents do a auto url_decode

Tags: php, file-get-contents, urldecode

I am doing the folowing on the URL

```
file_get_contents('https://xyz.com/login.php?app_data=%7B%22page%22%3A%22details%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2273%22%2C%22crp%22%3A%221%22%2C%22cip%22%3A%22%22%7D');
```

but I am receiving it at the other end as

```
app_data={"page":"details","id":"73","crp":"1","cip":""}
```

and not

```
app_data=%7B%22page%22%3A%22details%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2273%22%2C%22crp%22%3A%221%22%2C%22cip%22%3A%22%22%7D'
```

Code at other end:

```
if(isset($_GET['url']))
{
    log($_GET['url']);
}
```

`log` is just writing to a file.

**Answer** : No, but `$_GET` ***does***.

Comment: How are you receiving it? With a `$_GET['app_data']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

> **Note:**
>
> The GET variables are passed through [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

This applies to both keys and values (the latter is what causes your confusion). To get the result you want, you *either* need to double-encode on the client (which is a very ugly workaround):

```
$appdata = urlencode(urlencode('{"page":"details","id":"73","crp":"1","cip":""}'));
file_get_contents("https://xyz.com/login.php?app_data=$appdata");
```

Or just do it properly and post-process the string on the server side:

```
// $app_data will contain the nice, unescaped form
$app_data = $_GET['app_data']

// later if we need to pass $app_data in another request,
// we explicitly encode it again.
$app_data_encoded = urlencoded($app_data);
```

Comment: OK, basically I think we agree; there are 2 ways to make this work for the OP : either DOUBLE-`urlencode` the string at the caller, OR encode it ONCE in the caller and ONCE in the receiver.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: Yes. I justed wanted to clean up the confusion about *where the decoding actually happens*. The web server does *not* decode them, neither does `file_get_contents`!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution A :**

*Encode your `appdata` TWICE in the caller script*

```
// Caller script
$appdata = '"page":"details","id":"73","crp":"1","cip":""';
$appdata = urlencode(urlencode($appdata));

file_get_contents("https://xyz.com/login.php?app_data=$appdata");
```

**Solution B :**

*Encode your `appdata` ONCE in the caller script and ONCE in the receiver script*

```
// Caller script
$appdata = '"page":"details","id":"73","crp":"1","cip":""';
$appdata = urlencode($appdata);

file_get_contents("https://xyz.com/login.php?app_data=$appdata");
```

---

```
// Receiver script
$appdata = urlencode($_GET['app_data']);
```

And what you'll get is what you expect... ;-)

Comment: taht's adding a "" around app data

Comment: @WebDeveloper `file_get_contents` obviously does an `urldecode`... so... re-urlENCODE one more time ;-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: No it's not. It passes the URL through exactly as it is.

Comment: @NiklasB. And how is it that the string he gets is an exact same of what he'd get after it is `urldecode`d?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: Ahem, because PHP decodes the arguments for you on the server side before putting them into `$GET`?

Comment: @NiklasB. Well, ok... I think you put it right into words... makes sense... though the result is practically the same, huh?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: If `file_get_contents` would do `urldecode`, the result would not be a valid URL in general (otherwise, why was it escaped in the first place?). Also, it means that you can still get the raw URL on the server side using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` (on Apache).

Comment: @NiklasB. Point taken. Just got confused myself by the result... and did not think logically ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to get back to encoded form.

```
$result = urlencode($app_data);
echo $result;
```